# How do I build this Maven project from source?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, languagetool

I want to build the [LanguageTool](http://www.languagetool.org) Java project from source. This page gives basic instructions for obtaining the "Maven artifact" with all the sources:

http://languagetool.org/java-api/

I'm an expert Java developer but I've never used Maven before. Can someone please tell me how to get the LanguageTool project and all source code into Eclipse so I can modify and build it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of the page you linked ([Language Tool](http://www.languagetool.org/)) is another link to the svn repository.  That's where you'll get the source code and instructions on how to build the tool yourself.

In general, open source projects will highlight the maven artifact as it allows others to use their code in the easiest way possible.  Only a few folks like to build the code themselves so the links to the source repositories are often less conspicuous.

Comment: Also, you can look at their pom (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/org/languagetool/languagetool/1.9/) which contains the same information. Maven source download is designed to debug/trace - not modify the project.

Comment: @ptyx, your link appears to be broken.  It looks like there's no longer anything in the maven2 directory.

Comment: @dgoverde indeed - you can still find it on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.languagetool/languagetool/2.0.1 or other google links

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to do this.

Best is to start a basic maven project (manually or through a [Maven Archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html), import the sources in the [Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), and start adding dependencies to the pom.xml in order to get it to compile.

Libraries like commons,lucene,... are pretty easy to find in the various maven repositories).

Other libs you will probably have to install yourself in your [local repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) or [remote repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html).

There's a [maven plugin](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) for eclipse if that is your preferred IDE.